# How do I access an element of a struct in assembly?

Tags: c, arrays, assembly, struct

Given the following struct

```
typedef struct {
char valid;
char tag;
char block[4];
} line;
```

I am having trouble accessing the `tag` element of the struct in assembly. The function takes in an array of structs which are stored at `8(%ebp)`, and I have successfully been able to access the first byte of each struct in the array. However, I now need to access the `tag` byte, but cannot figure out how.

If I access the `valid` byte with:

`movl  (%eax, %ecx, 1),  %eax  # ecx = offset,eax = position of array`

How do I access the next part of the struct?

this is the C code. We are writing the `check_cache` function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

typedef struct {
    char valid;
    char tag;
    char block[4];
} line;

unsigned char check_cache(line cache[4], unsigned char addr);

int main() {
    line cache[4];

    cache[0].valid = 0x1;
    cache[0].tag = 0x0;
    cache[0].block[0] = 0xA;
    cache[0].block[1] = 0xB;
    cache[0].block[2] = 0xC;
    cache[0].block[3] = 0xD;

    cache[1].valid = 0x0;
        cache[1].tag = 0x7;

    cache[2].valid = 0x0;
        cache[2].tag = 0xA;

    cache[3].valid = 0x1;
        cache[3].tag = 0x3;
        cache[3].block[0] = 0x2A;
        cache[3].block[1] = 0x2B;
        cache[3].block[2] = 0x2C;
        cache[3].block[3] = 0x2D;

    unsigned char res;
    int input;
    unsigned char uc;
    do 
    {
        printf("Enter a memory address (0-255) for cache access: ");
        assert(scanf("%d", &input) == 1);
        uc = (unsigned char)input;
        res = check_cache(cache, uc);
        if(res == 0xFF)
            printf("cache MISS for address 0x%x\n", uc);
        else
            printf("cache HIT for 0x%x: 0x%x\n", uc, res);
    } while(uc);
    return(0);
}
```

This is my full assembly code so far:

```
.global check_cache

check_cache:
    pushl   %ebp
        movl    %esp,   %ebp

    movl    12(%ebp), %eax  
    movl    $0x3,     %ebx
    andl    %eax,     %ebx
    shrl    $0x2,     %eax
    movl    $0x3,     %ecx
    andl    %eax,     %ecx
    shrl    $0x2,     %eax
    movl    $0xF,     %edx
    andl    %eax,     %edx

    movl    8(%ebp),  %eax
    imull   $6,   %ecx
    movl    (%eax, %ecx, 1), %eax
    cmpl    $0x0,   %eax
    movl    $0, %esi    
    jle .L4 



    movl    (%eax),   %eax
    movl    4(%eax),  %eax  

    je  .L4

    popl    %ebp
    ret

.L4:    
    movl    $0xFF,    %eax
    popl    %ebp
    ret
```

Comment: Have you tried compiling that C struct to assembly source code to see what symbols are defined using `gcc -save-temps`? You could also add a function that access a struct member and see what it's assembly looks like.

Comment: to be honest, I'm not sure how to do this. This is part of a very large assignment that came with prewritten code. Should I include that?

Comment: Do not access `struct` elements using magic numbers in assaembler. Use a compiler you can pass the `offsetof()` or the elements as such in a C-compatible way. gcc is such a compiler.

Comment: Not sure if I understand @olaf, I'm not able to write C code for this as the assignment is to write an assembly program that accesses the struct

Comment: In `as` there is [.struct](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Struct.html).

Comment: Then your question is unclear. Do you have this `struct` defined in C code, or do you want to write assembler code which uses a `struct`? For the latter, you should not use the C tag or refer to C in general, because this would be a pure assembler question.

Comment: im going to update with the C code. We have to write a function that is part of the program.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the actual question: if `(%eax, %ecx, 1)` is the `valid` member then of course the `tag` is the next byte, thus `1(%eax, %ecx, 1)`.

Comment: if I store `8(%ebp)` in `%eax`, I understand that I am placing the contents of the address in `%eax`. The next command, `movl (%eax, %ecx, 1), %eax`, puts the contents of the first byte of the struct into `%eax`. So in order to get to the `tag` byte, should I first reset `%eax` to `8(%ebp)`? Or is there a way to increment `%eax` by one byte?

Comment: Yes, if you overwrite `eax` you need to reload it. But note that `movl` loads 4 bytes, not 1 so it already includes the `tag` too, and probably 2 bytes from the `block`. Chances are, you don't want this, so use `movb` with a different register.